# Getting this error while deploying filebeat "Exiting: No outputs are defined. Please define one under the output section."

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to deploy filebeat in one cluster and trying to send the logs into another cluster which has elastic search and kibana installed in it.
This is my yml file
`

```
---
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: es-beats
  namespace: elastic
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 7.12.1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elastic 
  config:
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
      - /var/log/containers/*.log
    - output.elasticsearch:
      # Array of hosts to connect to.
      hosts: ["https://<my-other-cluster-ip>:9200"]

      # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
      protocol: "https"

      username: "elastic"
      password: "mypass"
    - setup.kibana:
      host: "https://<my-other-cluster-ip>:9200"
      username: "elastic"
      password: "mypass"
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        containers:
        - name: filebeat
          volumeMounts:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            mountPath: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
        volumes:
        - name: varlogcontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
        - name: varlogpods
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/pods
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

`

beats is successfully installed and when i apply this file everything works fine but the pods don't get deployed and when I get pods the status says <kbd>CrashLoopBackOff</kbd>

I deployed the beats using k8 operators and want to get the logs into the other cluster I read the documentation but I am confused where do I enter the elasticsearch host and kibana host name and pass and what shall the output be.

Comment: I think with the k8s operator it is not possible to send logs to an elasticsearch in another cluster. You can only reference an elasticsearch installation in the same cluster.